# Lost git changes on Github

Tags: git, github

I just lost all my git changes. I committed and pushed all my changes, which seemed to work fine. Next a colleague pulls, commits and pushes his changes (to a single file). This somehow magically removed all my changes. He did not even perform a merge.

My commit: https://github.com/dma-dk/Embryo/tree/062eafa847813830eac0ca89957ccb9e2cff6d5f

His commit: https://github.com/dma-dk/Embryo/commit/7fb20aa37048e0385a97d4fc70903d582f34a0be

Does any one have an idea of why this happened and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My colleague did have a merge, which he had not pushed.